# Wordpress find category of custom post connected to custom post

Tags: php, wordpress

Below is my working code to change a custom text field in every post of type `lp_lesson` to some text. Each one of these `lp_lessons` are assigned a specific post (`lp_course`).

My question is how do I figure out which lesson is connected to which course? I have a space in my phpAdmin title `wp_learnpress_section_items` that have a `section_id` and an `item_id` but I don't know how to access these as I have tried: `$field_value = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'section_id', 1);`

The `section_id` references an array in my phpAdmin of `wp_learnpress_sections` and I would love to do this:

get the `item_id` which is equivalent to the post's `ID`. Then get the `section_id` associated with that `item_id`. Then get the `section_course_id` associated with that `section_id`. I have the logic down - I just don't know how to access these variables or items. I am guessing my `$field_value` is not the correct way to access these items.

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'win_9388244_format_lp_lesson' );

function win_9388244_format_lp_lesson() {
  //Get post type of lp_lesson
        $args = array(
         'post_type' => 'lp_lesson',
         'numberposts' => 99999
        );
        $posts = get_posts($args);
  foreach($posts as $post) {
    //if category == Test
    update_post_meta( $post->ID, 'wpk_icon_text', 'Test' ); 
  }
}
```

Edit: I have found that `$post->ID` gives me the post's ID, but not the rest of the variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who wants to do something similar I got it to work.

```
function win_9388244_format_lp_lesson() {
  //Get post type of lp_lesson
  $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'lp_lesson',
    'numberposts' => 99999
  );
  $posts = get_posts($args);
  global $wpdb;
  $sections = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT section_item_id, section_id, item_id FROM wp_learnpress_section_items", ARRAY_A );
  $items = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT section_course_id, section_id FROM wp_learnpress_sections", ARRAY_A );
  foreach($posts as $post) {
    $lesson_id = $post->ID;
    foreach($sections as $section) {
      if($section['item_id'] == $lesson_id) {
        $currentSection = $section['section_id'];
        foreach($items as $item) {
          if ($item['section_id'] == $currentSection) {
            $course_code = $item['section_course_id'];
            if ($course_code == 6177){
              update_post_meta( $post->ID, 'wpk_icon_text', 'Time & Labor' ); 
            }
            else{
              update_post_meta( $post->ID, 'wpk_icon_text', 'Lesson' );
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```